# How do I write recursion to output nested messages?

Tags: javascript, recursion

There is data with user comments:

```
const mockData = [{
    'id': 1,
    'parentId': 2,
    'text': 'id 1',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T13:12:20+03:00')
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'parentId': null,
    'text': 'id 2',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T13:04:37+03:00')
}, {
    'id': 3,
    'parentId': 2,
    'text': 'id 3',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T13:05:40+03:00')
}, {
    'id': 4,
    'parentId': 1,
    'text': 'id 4',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T13:10:02+03:00')
}, {
    'id': 5,
    'parentId': 6,
    'text': 'id 5',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T13:14:33+03:00')
}, {
    'id': 6,
    'parentId': null,
    'text': 'id 6',
    'date': new Date('2020-03-11T11:05:33+03:00')
}]
```

It is necessary to display messages with parentId === null, and below them - the corresponding answers. Just like a regular chat.

I started writing:

```
function sortByDate(data) {
  return data.sort(function compare(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });
}

export const findChildrenComments = (data, parentId = null) => {
  return sortByDate(data.filter(comment => comment.parentId === parentId));
};

const convert = mockData => {
  let arr = [];
  const parentArr = findChildrenComments(data);
  parentArr.forEach(element => {
      arr.push(element)
    const child1 = findChildrenComments(data,element.parentId)

  });
};
```

but how do I turn that into recursion?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const mockData = [
    { id: 1, parentId: 2, text: "id 1", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:12:20+03:00") },
    { id: 2, parentId: null, text: "id 2", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:04:37+03:00") },
    { id: 3, parentId: 2, text: "id 3", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:05:40+03:00") },
    { id: 4, parentId: 1, text: "id 4", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:10:02+03:00") },
    { id: 5, parentId: 6, text: "id 5", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:14:33+03:00") },
    { id: 6, parentId: null, text: "id 6", date: new Date("2020-03-11T11:05:33+03:00") },
].sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);

const recursion = parentId =>
    mockData.filter(c => c.parentId === parentId).map(c => ({ ...c, children: recursion(c.id) }));

console.log(recursion(null));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const makeTree = (categories, parent) => {
    const node = {};
    categories
        .filter(c => c.parentId === parent)
        .forEach(c => {
            node[c.id] = makeTree(categories, c.id);
            Object.assign(node[c.id], c);
        });
    return node;
}

console.log(makeTree(mockData, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple recursive function to flatten an array like this into a tree would be this `makeForest`:

```js
const makeForest = (id, xs) => 
  xs .filter (({parentId}) => parentId == id)
     .map (({id, parentId, ...rest}) => ({id, ...rest, children: makeForest (id, xs)}))

const mockData = [{id: 1, parentId: 2, text: "id 1", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:12:20+03:00")}, {id: 2, parentId: null, text: "id 2", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:04:37+03:00")}, {id: 3, parentId: 2, text: "id 3", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:05:40+03:00")}, {id: 4, parentId: 1, text: "id 4", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:10:02+03:00")}, {id: 5, parentId: 6, text: "id 5", date: new Date("2020-03-11T13:14:33+03:00")}, {id: 6, parentId: null, text: "id 6", date: new Date("2020-03-11T11:05:33+03:00")}]
  .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)

console .log (makeForest (null, mockData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(SO administrivia: There are too many questions like this.  We need to find a definitive one and start marking others as duplicates.  I'm just not sure what's a good base case.  This one might do, as the only unusual thing is the initial sort.)